# Filtrar DataGridView por Intervalo Entre Datas em VB.NET

Tags: winforms, vb.net, microsoft-access

Sou novo em programação e estou terminando um trabalho, porém estou com um problema que já me deparo por semanas e nao tenho conseguido resolver.

Criei um sistema simples que faz o cadastro das OSs (ordens de serviço), e em um *form* coloquei uma datagrid que puxa todas as OS.

Fiz um filtro que é para buscar os funcionários que digito na caixa de texto, porém ele busca todos os serviços feitos pelo nome digitado, entao preciso saber como fazer um segundo filtro, onde vou informar a data inicial e a final.

Exemplo: preciso saber o que o funcionário fez, então jogo o nome do funcionário na caixa e faço o filtro, e os serviços aparecem na `datagrid`, porem preciso saber como fazer outro filtro para filtrar somente as datas, depois coloco as datas em outro campo com um intervalo. ex: 10/10/2014 até 20/10/2014. Já tentei de algumas formas porém não consegui de maneira nenhuma.

Alguém poderia me explicar, por favor? Estou usando VB.NET e Access 2003.

Código:

```
Dim cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Firebird.mdb"
cn.Open()

Dim dt1 As DateTime = DateTimePicker1.Value.Date
Dim dt2 As DateTime = DateTimePicker2.Value.Date
'MsgBox(dt1)
Try

    MsgBox(dt1 + " " + dt2)

    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Dim Da As OleDbDataAdapter
    With Cmd
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .CommandText = "select * FROM OS where data between @datainicial AND @datafinal"
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@datainicial", dt1)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@datafinal", dt2)
        .Connection = cn
    End With

    With OSTableAdapter.Adapter
        .SelectCommand = cmd
        dt = New DataTable
        .Fill(dt)
        OSDataGridView.DataSource = dt
    End With

    cn.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: Você poderia colocar na sua pergunta um exemplo de código?

Comment: tentei usar este codigo aqui.. http://pastebin.com/65eS1m0L . porem.. creio que nao preciso fazer a busca na base de dados.. sendo que a datagrid ja esta com os resultados filtrados por nome do funcionario... nao sei se teria como filtrar apenas o campo 'data' da dg.

Comment: Você quer filtrar o resultado no `DataTable`, é isso?

Comment: tenho uma DataGridView .. nela esta filtrado o nome do funcionario com todos os serviços realizados por ele ... preciso agora filtrar o intervalo de datas, preciso ver os serviços feitos por este funcionario durante um certo periodo... entao tentei incluir dois DateTimePicker um sendo a data inicial, e outro a data Final... usei este codigo dentro do botao filtrar. porem... nao funcionou, ao certo nao sei se e preciso mesmo fazer a busca no banco.. ou se tem como filtrar somente a coluna da DataGrid, sem precisar fazer uma nova consulta a base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é preciso passar as datas como parâmetro. Você pode usar a propriedade `RowFilter` da sua `DataGridView` da seguinte forma:

```
DirectCast(OSDataGridView.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = "data > #" & DateTimePicker1.Value & "# and data < #" & DateTimePicker2.Value & "#"
```

Comment: nao apareceu a prorpiedade RowFilter , digitei todo o codigo como o acima  mas depois do OSDataGridView. , as unicas opçoes que me dao com Row .. nem uma é esta.

Comment: @VyniciusHenrique Você tem razão. Alterei a resposta.

Comment: deu um problema de Syntax com esse "(" do começo...

Comment: Não testei esse código, por isso. Atualizei de novo.

Comment: ocorreu um erro durante o teste ... Nao foi possivel converter um objeto do tipo "System.Windows.forms.BindingSource" no tipo "System.Data.DataTable" , vou tentar por o DateTimePicker.value em - DateTimePicker.value.Date

Comment: mesmo assim nao funcionou. nao entendo qual o motivo do erro,

Comment: Você precisa pegar a propriedade que tem os dados da sua `DataGridView` como um `DataTable`. Nela tem `DefaultView.RowFilter`, que é onde acontece o filtro efetivamente. Não estou podendo testar esse código pra você agora.

Comment: ` FirebirdDataSet.OS.DefaultView.RowFilter = "data > #" & DateTimePicker1.Value & "# and data < #" & DateTimePicker2.Value & "#" ` " Cadeia de caracteres não foi reconhecida como DateTime válido. "

Comment: @VyniciusHenrique Agora está mais fácil. Só converter os valores do `DateTimePicker`: `DateTimePicker1.Value.Date`.

Comment: Cigano, ja havia tentado tambem , porem nao funcionou, acha que pode ser no banco, onde deixei como texto o campo ?

Answer (score 0):

Tem como fazer um filtro pelo datatable também, após fazer a consulta sem os filtros de data.

Para isso basta criar algum coisa do tipo:

```
Dim filtro as String = "data >= '" & dt1 & "' and data <= '" & dt2 & "'"
Dim drFiltro() as Datarow = dt.Select(filtro)
OSDataGridView.DataSource = drFiltro
```

A solução que é o colega comentou usando o rowFilter também deve funcionar para DataViews. A vantagem de usar o Dataview é que você pode ter diferentes filtros nos dados sem alterar os dados originais, ou seja, sem precisar fazer uma nova consulta toda vez que quiser fazer um novo filtro.